# How to add URL parameter in a Retrofit @GET request in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am currently trying to fetch a JSONArray from a server using Retrofit in Kotlin. Here is the interface I am using:

```
interface TripsService {

    @GET("/coordsOfTrip{id}")
    fun getTripCoord(
            @Header("Authorization") token: String,
            @Query("id") id: Int
            ): Deferred<JSONArray>

    companion object{
        operator fun invoke(
            connectivityInterceptor: ConnectivityInterceptor
        ):TripsService{
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(connectivityInterceptor).build()
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl("https://someurl.com/")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(TripsService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

the desired url is: `https://someurl.com/coordsOfTrip?id=201`

I am getting the following error message:

> retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

I know the URL is working because I can access it via a browser.

Can someone please help me identify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change the parameter from

```
@GET("/coordsOfTrip{id}")
```

to

```
@GET("/coordsOfTrip")   // remove {id} part that's it
```

And you'd get the desired URL `https://someurl.com/coordsOfTrip?id=201`

If you want to use `{id}` in `GET()` then you've to use it like below

```
@GET("/coordsOfTrip{id}")
fun getTripCoord(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Path("id") id: Int    // use @Path() instead of @Query()
): Deferred<JSONArray>
```

But in your case it doesn't require. Follow the first method I mentioned.

For more check Retorfit's official documentation [URL Manipulation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/#api-declaration) part

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately using the @GET("/coordsOfTrip")  gives me the error "retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error" and using the @GET("/coordsOfTrip{id}") give me the error  "retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"

Comment: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error means there's an error in server script and it's not related to client side. Please debug the server code once and make sure that the server is receiving `id` and auth token properly.

Comment: From the documentation this seems like the correct solution: @GET("/coordsOfTrip")
 fun getTripCoord(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Query("id")  id:Int);

Comment: If the problem is an error in the server script, then shouldn't using that URL in a browser cause the same problem? Because I see the response correctly in a browser.

Comment: @PhilBlais in browser you hard-coded 201 as id but while testing the same api in Retrofit make sure that whether id is actually sent to server or not. I assume that you're performing SQL operation based on the id. If doesn't concatenate id to SQL statement it'll throw an exception. Either debug server script or check server error log once. Read about [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

Comment: @Shashanth you were right, it was a problem on the server side! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
@GET("/coordsOfTrip{id}")
```

with:

```
@GET("/coordsOfTrip?id={id}")
```

Comment: That doesn work, I get a "URL query string "id={id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query."