# How to get a parameter in the link ? - Using Android Studio (Retrofit)

Tags: android, retrofit, searchbar

Im trying to pass an intitle parameter in this link using retrofit. My api is stack exchange.

search?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

I tried this way but it didnt work.

```
    Call<ResponseModelsSearch.Search> void getSearch(@Query("intitle") String intitle);
```

Comment: try using @Path instead of @ Query. It should work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58567898/7874746